# OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications - how to call my AppEngine app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

In my desktop application I have successfully acquired OAuth2 access_token.

I can call successfully Google APIs by adding to the http request header:

```
Authorization: Bearer ya29.gQHsr_vr9P6nsEi06OKWkqKlvzD...
```

Now I would like to get the current user from http request - how do I do that? I don't want to implement Google Cloud Endpoints.

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
{
    //  How do I get the logged in user ?
    com.google.appengine.api.users.User googleUser =  ?;
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly.

You can do the following after getting credentials:

```
 /**
   * Send a request to the UserInfo API to retrieve the user's information.
   *
   * @param credentials OAuth 2.0 credentials to authorize the request.
   * @return User's information.
   * @throws NoUserIdException An error occurred.
   */
  static Userinfoplus getUserInfo(Credential credentials)
      throws NoUserIdException {
    Oauth2 userInfoService = new Oauth2.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credentials)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();
    Userinfoplus userInfo = null;
    try {
      userInfo = userInfoService.userinfo().get().execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
    if (userInfo != null && userInfo.getId() != null) {
      return userInfo;
    } else {
      throw new NoUserIdException();
    }
```

Source:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/credentials

Let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is already explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/). Slightly modified snippet taken from "OAuth service provider and App Engine" section of that link:

```java
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException;
import com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthService;
import com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthServiceFailureException;

// ...
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
  // ...
  User user = null;
  try {
    OAuthService oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
    user = oauth.getCurrentUser();

  } catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
    // The consumer made an invalid OAuth request, used an access token that was
    // revoked, or did not provide OAuth information.
    // ...
  }

  // Rest of your handler code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested this approach - but it's didn't work. I want to call my api from desktop application. Obtaining the OAuth2's access_token for instaled app is different from link you gave. [Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Comment: I see; but the link you shared explains how to get access_token's from the client application. My answer, on the other hand, has to do with server-side, i.e what you deploy on App Engine. If you correctly craft your requests from the desktop application that talks to your app server, that is, you manage to obtain a valid access_token, and embed this token in the 'Authorization' field of your headers (as you explained), then it should work. What errors are you experiencing exactly, server-side?